# Why can't I remove some files in Windows(7) from a python script?

Tags: windows-7, python

In Windows, some files, when tried to remove raises a **WindowsError**. The reason why I posted this here instead of SO is because the scripting side is less relevant than OS level permissions *(script works fine in Linux)*.
I'm of course the Administrator of these files, I have turned off the zone information so that no files are blocked, yet errors occur for many files. Most of these are files from the internet. Could I somehow work around this exception, say... try something else instead of os.remove(file)?

Comment: which error message do you get?

Comment: "Windows Error" [Error 5, access denied]

Answer (score 0):

`access denied` means you don't have the permissions to delete the files, due to [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). Run the script [as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token).